# Android how to auto increment version_code when next apk is generated?

Tags: android, gradle

Currently i have version_name = 1.0 and version_code = 1

I want to upgrade the version_code which is in version.properties in my app folder when i am generating an APK release of it.

Please help me?

Here is my build.gradle of my android app apk.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dummyproject"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 
                          'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never thought about such feature, may be useful... but note that there are some cases when you need to produce release-signed apk just for testing e.g. check some signing or proguard config works well. but still `versionCode` may be incremented, why not...

note that this feature will edit your code (should change `versionCode` permanently, for next +1), so for this purpose (if possible) may exist some plugin or script for Android Studio, but gradle itself won't edit own currently-executing build file. you may override this value (`versionCode`) for release flavor, but this will be fixed still, as every build command will set `versionCode=versionCode+1` temporary without knowledge how many builds were made previously